# Different styles for Font Icons

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, fonts, font-awesome

I'm using Font Awesome and icomoon icons for my web application by defining font faces.

Here is the font-face configuration:

```
@font-face {
  font-family : 'FontAwesome';
  src         : url('../fonts/font-awesome-4.2.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?32940503');
  src         : url('../fonts/font-awesome-4.2.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?32940503#iefix')
        format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/font-awesome-4.2.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?32940503')
        format('woff'), url('../fonts/font-awesome-4.2.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?32940503') format('truetype'),
        url('../fonts/font-awesome-4.2.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?32940503#FontAwesome') format('svg');
  font-weight : normal;
  font-style  : normal;
}
```

When I use the icons through `span` tags, I see them darker than the icon configuration - I use them with Ext JS.

Here is the explanation of my issue:

[image: explanation]

**How can I use the darker icons at anywhere I want?**

p.s. Ext JS provices `glyph` configuration for its components such as panels, forms, buttons etc. [API Docs](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-cfg-glyph)

**Example Usage:**

A panel icon config - **first icon in the screenshot**: `glyph: 'xf00c@FontAwesome'`

Comment: Show your HTML code and the specific styling for the relevant element.

Comment: the post is updated and the icon configuration is added.

Comment: Only the css doesn't tell much. Please post some HTML.

Comment: ExtJS is an application development framework based on Javascript; so I do not write any HTML code; ui components are implemented with Object-oriented Javascript. So all I do with HTML is importing the necessary sources such as Javascript, CSS files & images. So it will not make sense to share a HTML file with just traditional imports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default glyph opacity is set to `0.5`. You should override style to make it more opaque:

```
.x-btn-icon-el-default-small.x-btn-glyph, 
.x-btn-icon-el-default-medium.x-btn-glyph, 
.x-btn-icon-el-default-large.x-btn-glyph,
.x-btn-icon-el-default-toolbar-small.x-btn-glyph,
.x-btn-icon-el-default-toolbar-medium.x-btn-glyph,
.x-btn-icon-el-default-toolbar-large.x-btn-glyph
{
    opacity: 1.0;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/89aeduo6/8/ (it uses Arial as glyph font)

Comment: Works for me, example: http://jsfiddle.net/89aeduo6/8/ (I used arial there, but same applies for other fonts).
If you have other theme, there might also be some other styles applied to glyphs, use some developer tools to identify differences.
If you still will have problem, try to reproduce it on fiddle.

Comment: dou you have a chance to look the fiddle here - I forked yours and just changed the icon of the button to : 'xf067@FontAwesome' which is a simple 'plus' icon http://jsfiddle.net/talhakabakus/gLb8jbtm/

Comment: And I see the same color on this fiddle for both icons (http://jsfiddle.net/gLb8jbtm/2/). 
What browser do you use?

Comment: I use Chrome on Ubuntu - Version 39.0.2171.95 (64-bit)

Comment: On chrome you should be good, only old IE has other CSS rules for opacity. It looks like this on my PC: http://imgur.com/VMhVxvr

Comment: I did not get the reason but when I added CSS rules separately it worked! Due to I use small buttons in toolbars, `.x-btn-default-toolbar-small .x-btn-glyph {
    opacity: 1;
}` did the job.